# Is Kausika Bhashya on Vedas available in English?

Tags: vedas

In [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=up0-AAAAcAAJ&pg=PR6&dq=the%20commentary%20on%20vedas%20by%20Sayana%20not%20entirely%20of%20his%20own&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixlfCFxPXjAhWH4nMBHe00DSIQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=the%20commentary%20on%20vedas%20by%20Sayana%20not%20entirely%20of%20his%20own&f=false) on the Aitareya Brahamanam, it was stated that there exists Kausika Bhashya on Vedas, which was more ancient to Sayana's commentary on Vedas.

If that is true, do we have that book with English translation in pdf form?